# Python remove stop words from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove the stop words from my column "tweets". How do I iterative over each row and each item?

```
pos_tweets = [('I love this car', 'positive'),
    ('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
    ('I feel great this morning', 'positive'),
    ('I am so excited about the concert', 'positive'),
    ('He is my best friend', 'positive')]

test = pd.DataFrame(pos_tweets)
test.columns = ["tweet","class"]
test["tweet"] = test["tweet"].str.lower().str.split()

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
```

Comment: old post, but for reference, the stop words will have words like "i" and "a". @EdChum your code will cause all the words to be ruined because of that

Comment: @user3120554 probably you could sort the stopwords based on spaces and length.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Using List Comprehension

```
test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
```

Returns:

```
0               [love, car]
1           [view, amazing]
2    [feel, great, morning]
3        [excited, concert]
4            [best, friend]
```

Comment: This does not maintain the string, so you will be unable to search for word combinations once you remove the stop words.  Ed Chum's comment above maintains the string.

Comment: i need to add `str(x).split()` and wil be `test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in str(x).split() if item not in stopwords.words('spanish')])` because show a error that said  **'float' object is not iterable**

Comment: @Alex Montoya, I found this question and answer: I am trying to apply what you suggested, but I am getting empty column: `df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in str(x).split() if item not in stop])`. Do you know what it can cause it? (I would like to avoid a duplicate question) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 107):

We can import `stopwords` from `nltk.corpus` as below. With that, We exclude stopwords with Python's list comprehension and `pandas.DataFrame.apply`.

```py
# Import stopwords with nltk.
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

pos_tweets = [('I love this car', 'positive'),
    ('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
    ('I feel great this morning', 'positive'),
    ('I am so excited about the concert', 'positive'),
    ('He is my best friend', 'positive')]

test = pd.DataFrame(pos_tweets)
test.columns = ["tweet","class"]

# Exclude stopwords with Python's list comprehension and pandas.DataFrame.apply.
test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
print(test)
# Out[40]:
#                                tweet     class tweet_without_stopwords
# 0                    I love this car  positive              I love car
# 1               This view is amazing  positive       This view amazing
# 2          I feel great this morning  positive    I feel great morning
# 3  I am so excited about the concert  positive       I excited concert
# 4               He is my best friend  positive          He best friend
```

It can also be excluded by using `pandas.Series.str.replace`.

```py
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stop))
test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['tweet'].str.replace(pat, '')
test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['tweet_without_stopwords'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
# Same results.
# 0              I love car
# 1       This view amazing
# 2    I feel great morning
# 3       I excited concert
# 4          He best friend
```

If you can not import stopwords, you can download as follows.

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Another way to answer is to import `text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS` from `sklearn.feature_extraction`.

```py
# Import stopwords with scikit-learn
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
stop = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
```

**Notice that the number of words in the scikit-learn stopwords and nltk stopwords are different.**

Comment: what does "r'\b(?:{})\b'" do?

Comment: what if there is more than one column in the dataframe?  When I try to apply this to more than one column I get a KeyError

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` when i try to run this code

Comment: Almost worked for me, except that I had to wrap x in str() as in *word for word in str(x).split() if word not in stop*. I am using pandas 1.1.2 and Python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 8):

Check out pd.DataFrame.replace(), it might work for you:

```
In [42]: test.replace(to_replace='I', value="",regex=True)
Out[42]:
                              tweet     class
0                     love this car  positive
1              This view is amazing  positive
2           feel great this morning  positive
3   am so excited about the concert  positive
4              He is my best friend  positive
```

Edit : `replace()` would search for string(and even substrings). For e.g. it would replace `rk` from `work` if `rk` is a stopword which sometimes is not expected.

Hence the use of `regex` here :

```
for i in stop :
    test = test.replace(to_replace=r'\b%s\b'%i, value="",regex=True)
```

Comment: worked well! just thought of updating the answer with more cases

Answer (score 8):

If you would like something simple but not get back a list of words:

```
test["tweet"].apply(lambda words: ' '.join(word.lower() for word in words.split() if word not in stop))
```

Where stop is defined as OP did.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that using list comprehension is slower hence I suggest using pandas.Series.str.replace() which is much faster.

```
for i in stop:  
    test['tweet'] = test['tweet'].str.replace(' '+i+' ', ' ')
```

Where stop is defined as

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
```