# Python remove customized stop words from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was following the next question: [Python remove stop words from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523254/python-remove-stop-words-from-pandas-dataframe/38846564)

but it doesnt work for me for a customized stop words list, check out this code:

```
 pos_tweets = [('I love this car', 'positive'),
('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
('I feel great this morning', 'positive'),
('I am so excited about the concert', 'positive'),
('He is my best friend', 'positive')] 

import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame(pos_tweets)


test.columns = ["tweet","col2"]
test["tweet"] = test["tweet"].str.lower().str.split()

stop =  ['love','car','amazing']

test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop)

print test
```

the result is:

```
                                   tweet      col2
0                       [i, love, this, car]  positive
1                  [this, view, is, amazing]  positive
2            [i, feel, great, this, morning]  positive
3  [i, am, so, excited, about, the, concert]  positive
4                 [he, is, my, best, friend]  positive
```

the words love, car and amazing are still there, what Im missing?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign output back to column `tweet`:

```
test['tweet'] = test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])

print (test)
                                       tweet      col2
0                                  [i, this]  positive
1                           [this, view, is]  positive
2            [i, feel, great, this, morning]  positive
3  [i, am, so, excited, about, the, concert]  positive
4                 [he, is, my, best, friend]  positive
```

Comment: your solution worked pperfectly! one more question, what I have to do to remove the commas from the text like:

                                           tweet      col2
    0                                  [i this]  positive
    1                           [this view is]  positive
2            [i feel great this morning]  positive
3  [i am so excited about the concert]  positive
4                 [he is my best friend]  positive

Comment: Do you need convert list to strings for each row?