# Removing nltk stopwords from csv DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nltk, corpus

I'm attempting to remove stopwords from the following DataFrame read from a .csv. It's basically a long list of bigrams and the frequency of their occurence in a dataset of shampoo labels.

The goal is to remove the whole row when a stopword appears in either column 'word1' or 'word2'.

```
                        word1                      word2  frequency
0                       nicht                         in       3069
1                        wenn                        sie       2729
2                         von                    kindern       2108
3                         die                      hände       2094
4                        darf                      nicht       2091
5                       hände                        von       2091
6                      citric                       acid       2088
7                     kindern                   gelangen       2082
8                         sie                      einen       2053
9                         mit                        den       2023
10                       eine                   reaktion       1976
```

So far however, I've not even managed to delete a row based on only column 'word1' when it matches with a German stopword from nltk.

The code I use is based on a previous question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523254/python-remove-stop-words-from-pandas-dataframe).

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop = stopwords.words('german')

df = pd.read_table("myfile.csv", sep=";")
df.columns = ["word1","word2","frequency"]

df["word1"] = df["word1"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))

print(df)
```

The error I'm getting is:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

I totally understand that I'm at fault here for not understanding the called function. I'm trying to develop an understanding of pandas & nltk while I'm doing a course on the side, but this isn't really going anywhere :)

Once the DataFrame is cleaned of the stopwords, the goal is to write it into a new CSV. But that's for a later stage.

EDIT: title change for clarification

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Could you please include the first couple of lines of "myfile.csv" in the question.

Comment: The problem is solved. However if you're interested; here's a link to a dummy CSV with the first 100 rows: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YT_QELpSJ0Rm4iLjCSznGD_8KwFh7kOQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this purpose. Here, created a new column **temp**. The values of **temp** are **False** if any of **word1** or **word2** are in **stop**. Remove those rows whose **temp** value is **False**. Lastly, drop that **temp** column and Write to a new csv file. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop = stopwords.words('english')
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=";")


df["temp"] = [True  if row.word1 not in stop and row.word2 not in stop else False for index, row in df.iterrows()]
df = df[df.temp == True]
df.drop('temp', axis=1, inplace=True)

df.to_csv("myfile_out.csv", sep=';')
```

Answer (score -1):

The *apply*-function does not delete any rows. It just maps a function onto every element of the Series *df["word1"]*. Also, your entries in column *"word1"* seem to be of type *list* and not of type *string*.

However, if *df* were a pandas DataFrame containing a column *"word1"* with strings in it, just do this

```
df = df[~df["word1"].isin(stop)]
```

... and you drop all entries from df, where "word1" is in stop. Here *~* is the negation operator, so it means *not*. The *some_series.isin(some_iterable)* method returns a Series with the same indices as *some_series*, where every entry is a boolean denoting whether the respective entry in *some_series* is contained in *some_iterable*.

Generally, you can select slices from a DataFrame with

```
df[Series of booleans]
```

where "Series" means a pandas Series. Since pandas Series' work with comparative operators, you can do things like

```
df[df["frequency"] > 2060]
```

which returns a DataFrame containing only the rows with a frequency-value higher than 2060.

**EDIT: I'm not sure if the downvote came from you, but if the code provided here does not work, you should show a few lines of your .csv-file, because from your code alone we can not know what your DataFrame looks like exactly.**

Cheers,
Silas

Comment: Downvote didn't come from me. I'm trying it out right now :)