# how to remove common words from a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[Value counts of words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlNsY.png)

How do I remove common words like 'to','and','from','this'. I am only interested in keeping the words like 'AI','Data','Learning','Machine','Artificial'.

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407993/7053679

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to remove are the stopwords like 'to','the' etc. nltk has a predefined list of stop words:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words

['i',
 'me',
 'my',
 'myself',
 'we',
 'our',
 'ours',
 'ourselves',
 'you',...
```

You can use np.where to replace the stopwords with np.nan

```
title_analysis['new_col'] = np.where(title_analysis['words'].str.contains(stopwords), np.nan, title_analysis['words'])
```

Then do value_counts()

```
title_analysis['new_col'].value_counts()
```

If you have your own set of words that you want to ignore, just replace `stop_words` with your list of words.