# How to remove words from a data frame that are not in list in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am a beginner on working on non-English NLP, I want to clean all words in a data frame that are not contained in list `kata_dasar` :

My code is :

```
df['tweet']= [' '.join(w for w in p.split() if w in kata_dasar) for p in df['tweet']]
```

But it is not working, Please help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  When you say that it doesn't work, could you be more specific?  Is your code giving you an error or is it not functioning as you expect?

Comment: You can find a similar question at [Python remove stop words from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523254/python-remove-stop-words-from-pandas-dataframe/29523440#29523440).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you find yourself tempted to write a for-loop to iterate over rows of a dataframe, stop, and try to find a way to write it with `apply` instead :

```
df['tweet'] = df.tweet.apply(lambda p: ' '.join(w for w in p.split() if w in kata_dasar))
```