# Remove stopwords from words frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove stopwords from these data

```
     DateTime             Clean 
    2020-01-07             then       28
                            and       28
                          pizza       14
                        capital       14

    ... ... ...
    2020-03-31          college       14
                        included      14
                          of          14
    ...........
```

The data comes from

```
df4.groupby('DateTime').agg({'Clean': 'value_counts'}).rename(columns={'Clean': 'Count'}).groupby('DateTime').head(4)
```

How can I remove these stopwords from this frequency list?

Data sample before grouping (raw data):

```
Text                                                     Clean
all information regarding the state of art ...       [all, information, regarding, the, state, of, art ...
all information regarding the state of art ...       [all, information, regarding, the, state, of, art ...
to get a good result you should ...     [to, get, a, good ,...
```

The first is the text that I need to tokenize. Clean should contain tokenisation for each text. I would need to see frequency of words by datetime as shown below, but not including stop words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python remove stop words from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523254/python-remove-stop-words-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I did     `remove_words = list(stopwords.words('english'))+list(more_stop)` and     `df4.Clean=df4.Clean.apply(lambda x: list(word for word in x.split() if word not in remove_words))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use stopwords from `nltk`

  - They load as a list
- Update the nltk Collections by `import nltk` and then `nltk.download()`

```py
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# stop words list
stop = stopwords.words('english')

# data and dataframe
data = {'Text': ['all information regarding the state of art',
                 'all information regarding the state of art',
                 'to get a good result you should'],
        'DateTime': ['2020-01-07', '2020-02-04', '2020-03-06']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# all strings to lowercase, strip whitespace from the ends, and split on space
df.Text = df.Text.str.lower().str.strip().str.split()

# remove stop words from Text
df['Clean'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: [w.strip() for w in x if w.strip() not in stop])

# explode lists
df = df.explode('Clean')

# groupby DateTime and Clean
dfg = df.groupby(['DateTime', 'Clean']).agg({'Clean': 'count'})

                        Clean
DateTime   Clean             
2020-01-07 art              1
           information      1
           regarding        1
           state            1
2020-02-04 art              1
           information      1
           regarding        1
           state            1
2020-03-06 get              1
           good             1
           result           1
```