# I'm trying to remove certain words from a column on each row in my dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm still trying to understand how pandas works please bear with me. In this exercise, I,m trying to access a particular column ['Without Stop Words'] on each row which has a list of words. I wish to remove certain words from each row of that column. the words to be removed have been specified in a dictionary called {'stop_words_dict'}. here's my code, but the dataframe seems to be unchanged after running it.

```
def stop_words_remover(df):
    # your code here
    df['Without Stop Words']= df['Tweets'].str.lower().str.split()
    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        for word in df['Without Stop Words']:
            if word in stop_words_dict.items():
                df['Without Stop Words'][i] = df['Without Stop Words'].str.remove(word)
                
    return df
```

this is how the input looks like

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlZhD.png)
[EXPECTED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0SzL.png)

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of input / expected output (as text)

Comment: I have included the samples. thanks

Comment: This is not reproducible, please do not use images

Comment: i really cant get to copy the text and make it appear nice but here's the link to the csv file., you may want to create a dataframe off the file "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Explore-AI/Public-Data/master/Data/twitter_nov_2019.csv"

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, it's generally a bad idea to loop over your dataframe row by row to try to change rows. Instead, try using methods like .apply().

An example for stopwords, together with list comprehension:

```
test['Tweets'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop_words_dict.items()])
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29523440/12904151 for more context.