# How can I filter a column in pandas and extract only nouns/adjectives/verbs from it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, text

In general, I have a dataset of true/fake news. I coded and visualized a frequency analysis of words, but the problem is that the most common words are [the, a, he, were, has, etc]. But I need any words with sense (nouns, adjectives or verbs)
Lets imagine that we have such a dataframe:

```py
d = {'word': ['tiger', 'the','bear','fluffy','jump','were','he']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So, we got this:

`Word = ['tiger','the','bear','fluffy','jump,'were,'he']`

What can I do to get this:

`Word = ['tiger','bear','fluffy','jump,'were']`

I will be really thanksfull for any help!

I have tried the "textblob" library, but I think that is impasse...

Comment: Maybe check [how to remove stop words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523254/python-remove-stop-words-from-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: It seems like your question is how to determine the part of speech from a list of words and filter based on that. Is that correct?

Comment: @erip , you're correct. In general, I have a dataset of true/fake news. I coded and visualized a frequency analysis of words, but the problem is that the most common words are [the, a, he, were, has, etc]. But I need any words with sense (nouns, adjectives or verbs)